# Limitation on document count for azure search S3 HD pricing tier

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

When I read the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity) I see below info

"For S3 High Density services created after late 2017, the 200 million document per partition has been removed but the 1 million document per index limit remains."

I wanted to confirm if 1 million document limit still exists for S3 HD index or this limit has also been removed recently?

Comment: Yes you can't post data above 32000 you need to create data in batches wise then you are able to post data in azure

Comment: I got the answer. 1 million document limit still exists for S3 HD indexes

Comment: Can you please shared document link if possible it's helping me a lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the article remains valid. So 1 Million upper document limit for search indexes in S3 HD service tier remains valid now.

Answer (score 0):

Same issues I have faced then I'm converting data into batches.

Please modify the code as per your requirement.

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.Items.Count; i = i + 31500)
{
    searchItems = result.Items.Skip(i).Take(31500);
    actionList = new List<IndexAction<AzureSearchItem>>();
    foreach (var item in searchItems)
    {
        actionList.Add(IndexAction.MergeOrUpload(AzureHelper.FormatSearchItem(item)));
    }
    PostBulkAssortmentDocuments(actionList.AsEnumerable());
}

public virtual void PostBulkAssortmentDocuments(IEnumerable<IndexAction<AzureSearchItem>> actions)
{
    if (actions.Count() == 0)
        return;

    var batch = IndexBatch.New(actions);

    try
    {
        var data = GetIndexClient(IndexName).Documents.Index(batch);

        var passResultCount = data.Results.Where(x => x.Succeeded).Count();
        var failResultCount = data.Results.Where(x => x.Succeeded == false).Count();
        var MessageResult = data.Results.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ErrorMessage));
        var keyResult = data.Results.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Key)).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
        var unikKey = keyResult.Distinct().ToList();
        string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    }
    catch (IndexBatchException e)
    {
        // Sometimes when your Search service is under load, indexing will fail for some of the documents in
        // the batch. Depending on your application, you can take compensating actions like delaying and
        // retrying. For this simple demo, we just log the failed document keys and continue.
        Console.WriteLine(
            "Failed to index some of the documents: {0}",
            String.Join(", ", e.IndexingResults.Where(r => !r.Succeeded).Select(r => r.Key)));

        this.WriteToFile("Error - PostBulkAssortmentDocuments -" + e.Message);
    }
}
```